# opencv2: bicubic interpolation while resizing image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to do image resizing using the app `cv2.resize`. I would like to do 
bicubic interpolation while resizing. How would I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread('source to image here')
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, fx=scale_x, fy=scale_y, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

I haven't tested it out. Check http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize for more details

Comment: that's probably cv2.INTER_CUBIC